# Checking for Max and Min on different columns Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, compare, google-sheets-formula

The following code does work as intended, it is comparing a in B4 and in C4.

If B4 is a lower number than C4, it will replace C4 with the new lower number.

The loop is going through all other rows, this works fine.

```
function recordMinSellPrice() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var numberRange = 4;
  
  for(var i= 0; i < 5;i++ )
  {
     var test = "B"+ numberRange+":"+"C" + numberRange;
     var range = sheet.getRange(test);
     var values = range.getValues()[0];
     range.setValues([[values[0], Math.min(values[0], values[1])]]);
     numberRange++;
  }
}
```

The code below doesn't work as intended. I want to Compare column B with column D instead of C on the code above.

But when I run this I get an exception:

> Exception: The amount of columns in the code is not matching with the amount of columns in the range. The code has 2, but the range has 3.

I think it has to do something with this part; var test = "B"+ numberRange+":"+"D" + numberRange;

I think its currently also selecting C + numberRange. but i dont want to compare to C + numberRange.

The code should compare B4 with D4.
if B4 is larger than D4.
replace D4 with B4.
Start looping.

```
function recordMaxSellPrice() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var numberRange = 4;
  
  for(var i= 0; i < 5;i++ )
  {
     var test = "B"+ numberRange+":"+"D" + numberRange;
     var range = sheet.getRange(test);
     var values = range.getValues()[0];
     range.setValues([[values[0], Math.max(values[0], values[1])]]);
     numberRange++;
  }
}
```

I tried to explain my problem as good as i can.

Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: Do you know javascript arrays?

Comment: no i dont sadly

Comment: Why don't you take a [quick detour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#array_object) to know basics and then try to address your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case. Here is the example how it could be done in accordance with [the best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices?hl=en):

```
function recordMaxSellPrice() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues(); // get all data from the sheet

  // process the data with no redundant calls to the server
  for (var row in data) {
    data[row][3] = (data[row][3] > data[row][1]) ? data[row][3] : data[row][1]
  }
  
  // set updated data back on the sheet
  range.setValues(data);
}
```

`data[row][1]` is cell of column B in the row

`data[row][3]` is cell of column D in the row

Comment: Nitpicking :)  If OP has a formula in C(say `=D1+5`), it'll be destroyed during this op.

Comment: Alas. Fair point :)

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom part

```
range.setValues([[values[0], Math.max(values[0], values[1])]]);
```

You are only passing 2 values... 2 cells to setValues.

However, the range that you are reading has 3 cells, B, C and D

So you have to set 3 values in the setValues command.

```
range.setValues([[B,C,D]]);
```

Comment: So what do i have to do when C has to be ignored? of left unchanged?

Comment: Just insert the same value back, you are reading it. Try this

range.setValues([[values[0], values[1], Math.max(values[0], values[1])]]);

Comment: Probably it should be: `range.setValues([[values[0], values[1], Math.max(values[0], values[2])]]);` but the code is not exactly efficient. I think it's very slow.

Comment: Also, B is values[0], C is values[1] and D is values[2]... just to make sure your code is comparing the correct columns...

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to simply use `forEach()`  to dynamically check each column data or numbers and replace column D's if value is greater than column B

```
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 const ws = ss.getActiveSheet();
 const colB = ws.getRange(1,2,ws.getLastRow(),1).getValues(); //get column B data
 const colD = ws.getRange(1,4,ws.getLastRow(),1).getValues(); //get column D data

// compare both columns data and replace col D if value is greater than col B. You can use this vice versa. Just change the comparison operator
 colB.forEach(([num],i) => {   
   if(num < colD[i][0]) ws.getRange( i+1,4,1,1).setValue([num]) 
 })
}
```